# Why does this break my school computers?

Tags: shell-script, kill

my school uses sunrays and Linux mint and when i make a sh file with this code in it and it breaks my login.

```
while :
    do
    kill -9 -1

done
```

Comment: Just learn the basics about Unix and processes or have a look at `man kill`. This simply kill ALL your processes, without waiting for them to finish ... your login shell included.

Comment: *Kernel Panic: Undefined* I wouldn't be surprised if the computer stops working because it cant even locate where its boot-partition is.

Comment: This is a good question. Running this loop should be equivalent to just running `kill -9 -1` outside of a loop; the loop should not continue running and should not have any permanent effect which leaves you unable to log in (if you don't run it as superuser). The `kill -9 -1` should instantly kill the interpreter which is running the loop, so there actually is no loop.

Answer (score 4):

`-9` tells kill to instantly terminate a process.

`-1` causes all processes with a pid larger than 1 are signaled.

So you are killing all you the processes you can, which will be any that you have run including the script, bash, your window manager and all of your applications.

Once your window manager exits so does your x-session effectively logging you out.

Comment: i cant log back in if i do a loop how does that still run if im logged out?

Comment: You have killed everything in a very unclean manner, it's possible your script is still running - best advice do not do this.

Comment: @MichaelDaffin How can the script be running? The `-1` includes the calling process and its parent too. If `kill` is an external process, it kills the parent shell (and itself). If it's a shell built-in, the shell kills itself when that is invoked. Either way, the loop cannot continue.

Comment: Thats the theory, but since it kills future sessions something weird is going on. It is hard to say exactly what without more details (like a process list captured by another user).